# Übersetzung von "what is shown on..."

Tags: translation, word-choice

Es handelt sich um unpersönliche Sätze.

Beispiel:

> What is *shown* on the screen/display/clock/usw?

Was wäre die korrekte Übersetzung für den vorstehenden Satz?

Meiner Meinung nach ist *stehen* die Antwort:

> Ein Wort *steht* in einem Brief.
>
> Aktivitätsindex *steht* (oder *befindet sich*) am Display.

Gibt es eine genauere und richtigere Übersetzung?

Comment: Es würde helfen, wenn Du vollständige Beispielsätze angeben könntest, am besten mit Quelle oder Kontext. Und gib dazu bitte auch an (so gut es Dir möglich ist), wie Du sie verstehst und wo Du Probleme bei der Wiedergabe  in deutscher Sprache hast. Aktuell bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob Dein Problem nicht schon beim Verständnis des englischen Satzes liegt - das zu erklären wäre hier off-topic.

Comment: @Matthias Ich habe mein zweiten Beispiel geändert.

Comment: There's not *a single word* that fits for any contexts. In your "example" you can use different words. "anzeigen", "heißen" for instance.

Comment: @Em1 are there any translation with the word "einlesen"?

Comment: I don't think so. In this context "read" is usually not translated with "lesen". Possible though. But "einlesen" doesn't fit at all. – Regarding your edit: "es steht" is also a possibility.

Comment: @Em1 does"einlesen" have to be used only when i.e. a program reads the data from a disk/RAM? and how do I use this word? can you share an example? Thanks!

Comment: No, "sich in etwas einlesen" is also fine. – Anyway, your questions are way too broad. And I think you should get used to more basic stuff first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is about text, then you'd use "stehen".

> Auf dem Bildschirm steht....

If it is about a picture or a graph however, "stehen" does NOT work. In the phrasing you used I'd say

> Auf dem Display sieht man/kann man sehen...

This is common presentation lingo when it comes to describing graphs.

Answer (score 2):

"Was steht in dem Brief / auf dem Bildschirm / auf der Anzeige?"

Im Zusammenhang mit der Uhr würde man das genauso sagen, wenn man sich nicht auf die Uhrzeit bezieht: "Auf der Uhr steht der Name des Herstellers." aber "Es ist 10 Uhr".

Comment: This is true for text, but not for graphs. The original phrasing with "show" does allow for those too, though